# Upload an Image to firebase storage and save it to Firestore

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

at the beginning I would like to point out that I am a beginner in java and android.

I'm coding an application, which I can use to send a image of test result to database. For that moment I've got possibility to upload picture to Firebase Storage and I have no clue what should I do next, to import(?) image from storage to a database of specific user.

```
public class BloodTestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView imageSelected;
Button btn_uploadImage, btn_sendImage;
Uri uri;
StorageReference storageReference;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_blood_test);

    imageSelected = findViewById(R.id.viewSelectedImage);
    btn_uploadImage = findViewById(R.id.btn_uploadImage);
    btn_sendImage = findViewById(R.id.btn_sendImage);

    btn_uploadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            UploadImage();
        }
    });

    btn_sendImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            sendImage();

        }
    });
}

private void sendImage() {

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Sending test result...");
    progressDialog.show();

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss", Locale.CANADA);
    Date now = new Date();
    String fileName = format.format(now);
    storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("images/" + fileName);

    storageReference.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

            imageSelected.setImageURI(null);
            Toast.makeText(BloodTestActivity.this, "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (progressDialog.isShowing())
                progressDialog.dismiss();

        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

            if (progressDialog.isShowing())
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(BloodTestActivity.this, "Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}

private void UploadImage() {

    Dexter.withContext(this)
            .withPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse permissionGrantedResponse) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 101);
                }

                @Override
                public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse permissionDeniedResponse) {
                    Toast.makeText(BloodTestActivity.this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permissionRequest, PermissionToken permissionToken) {
                    permissionToken.cancelPermissionRequest();
                }
            }).check();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 101 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        uri = data.getData();
        imageSelected.setImageURI(uri);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: If you understand Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-upload-an-image-to-cloud-storage-and-save-the-url-in-firestore-42711ca1df46) will definitely help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/CloudStorageJetpackCompose).